# A simple png library for use in a c++ win32 tile-based game engine

Tags: c++, winapi, png, 2d, game-engine

I would like to write a win32 top-down 2d tile engine for a simple multiplayer game. I have researched various methods of loading and using PNGs in an windows application but I was wondering if anybody has any experience in this topic.

I would like all the networking, keyboard input and window management handled using the WinAPI and for this image library to only load and display the images in a grid format - a minimalist use of such a library, does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I have looked into SFML and SDL - also my knowledge in OpenGL in very very small.

Comment: freeimage (http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) is a very light and fast library supporting not only png, but all modern image formats. It is using libpng library for its png part, so probably you can work with libpng directly. I am not sure about the grid issues, I think there is some support for tiling, but I can be wrong on this.

Answer (score 2):

On windows PNG images can be loaded (or saved) using GDI+.

If you are writing a straight Win32 application (no DirectX etc) then this is probably the way to go.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

GDI+ can also do transparency, as well as polygons, elipses, splines, graduated fills and other simple drawing primitives.